# Reading playerprefs outputs a different value than real value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason, when I try to read a playerPref on Unity, it gives me a different value than the actual value in the file.

Value in file: 880.
Value being read: 792.

Please see this image:
[image: Different values]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It happens only in the editor?

Comment: Hi, the sole explanation i can think of is that you are looking at the wrong registry key,